# MYSQL Trigger definition -- 1064 error

Tags: mysql

I keep getting ERROR 1064 with the below trigger statement  "..for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5"
I have struggled with it for a couple of hours but just cannot figure out what is wrong!

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER status_upd AFTER UPDATE ON order_products
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF OLD.status_id != NEW.status_id THEN INSERT INTO op_status values(op_id,     NEW.status_id, curdate());
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Any suggestion, what I could be doing wrong.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be like this:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER status_upd AFTER UPDATE ON order_products 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF (OLD.status_id != NEW.status_id) THEN 
INSERT INTO op_status values(op_id,NEW.status_id, curdate());
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

You were missing the `END IF;`.

Comment: I added the little explanation at the end for you. And a +1 for spotting the missing bits.